# my jquery plugin not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have my own jquery plugin for my app. Its working fine for first callbacks and the second callbacks are not assigning.

```
$('element1').myplugin({callback:foo});
$('element2').myplugin({callback:bla});
```

second callback not working always calling 'foo'.

plugin code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function(options) {
          //some code.
          options.callback();
        }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It sounds like there's a bug with your plugin. Can you post the source code (the minimum amount it takes to still see the bug)?

Comment: Yeap - impossible to answer without seeing plugin code.

Comment: look at now the question

Answer (score 1):

Add `(jQuery)` at the end of the plugin. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wLEEK/
Here's why that works. Right now, your plugin looks like this:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.myplugin = function(options) {
      //some code.
      options.callback();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You're creating the jQuery method `myplugin`. But notice the code on the first line `function ($) {` and on the last line `}`. You've wrapped the plugin creation code in a function. The function accepts one argument that you call `$`. So the plugin creation code is inside a function, so we call that function using `(jQuery)` - passing in jQuery as an argument. It's kinda complicated, but here's a more familiar form to help you understand what's going on:

```
function createPlugin ($) {
  $.fn.myplugin = function(options) {
      //some code.
      options.callback();
    }
}//end of createPlugin
// myplugin isn't created yet; we need to call the function createPlugin
createPlugin(jQuery) // now myplugin is created
```

Comment: why jquery adding can u explain

Comment: If it's still not working can you create a test on jsfiddle.net? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you include any javascript then use upgraded version and also verifies the request which u pass and what u get in response....also make sure if there are one or more javascript include then use $.noConflict(true); may be this was help full to u........

Comment: can u give example i cant understand wt you are saying

Comment: Sorry i dont have any perticuler exapmle for this but i use this one and solve this type of error